# setting parent on child — circular reference

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

I have two classes, `Quest` and `Task`, that both extend `Event`. When `Quest` is instantiated, it calls its parent class `Event` to instantiate multiple `Tasks` on the `Quest` instance. These `Tasks` will belong to the `Quest` instance.

This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kvh5gwcs/) shows more succinctly what I mean. It's an endless circular reference of `task.parent.task.parent.task.parent...`, which for complex objects, I'm worried the impact of performance.

The children `Tasks` need to tell their parent `Quest` when certain events occur. So, when instantiating the `Quest`, and thereby instantiate the `Tasks`, I pass `this` so the child knows who it belongs to:

```
new childEventClass(eventObj, this));
```

The obvious problem here is you now have an infinite loop of setting the children on the parent, and the parent on the child, which now includes the children again, etc. Console.log the `Task`'s parent, you get:

```
Quest {
  id: 1,
  children: [
     Task: {
        id: 1,
        parent: Quest {
           id: 1,
           children: [
              Task: {
                id: 1,
                etc...
              },
              ...
           ]
        },
        ...
     },
     ...
  ]
}
```

**How can you avoid this?**

Other file:

```
this.quest = new Quest(quest);
```

Classes:

```
class Event {
    constructor(args, childEventClass, childEventClassName) {
        if (childEventClass && childEventClassName && args[childEventClassName] && args[childEventClassName].length > 0) {
            this.children = args[childEventClassName].map(eventObj => new childEventClass(eventObj, this));
        }
    }
    ...
}

class Quest extends Event {
    constructor(args) {
        super(args, Task, 'tasks');
    }
};

class Task extends Event {
    constructor(args, parent) {
        super(args, Activity, 'activities');
        this.parent = parent;
    }
};

class Activity extends Event {
    constructor(args, parent) {
        ...
    }
};
```

Comment: Instead of passing the parent object to the child, you may consider passing only the parent id to the child so it won't go for infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's an endless circular reference, which for complex objects, I'm worried the impact of performance.

No, it doesn't. And it has nothing to do with whether those objects are complex or not.

> So, when instantiating the Quest, and thereby instantiate the Tasks, I pass `this` so the child knows who it belongs to

That's a fine way to set up the circular references that you need.

> The obvious problem here is you now have an infinite loop of setting the children on the parent, and the parent on the child, which now includes the children again

…but it does not *set* them or try to create them again, so no you don't have any loop. Your code terminates.

> `Console.log` the Task's parent, you get…

not a problem. Yes, you can recursively expand those references. That's why they are called circular references - you can run through them like you run around a circle. But there's no harm if you don't do it.

Comment: I guess the browser garbage collection discards the circular reference. My concern was the circular pointers taking up memory.

Comment: Circular pointers don't take up any more memory than normal pointers. Yes, the garbage collector will pick up circular structures.

Comment: In retrospect, perhaps an events-based model is better as bidirectional ownership is typically bad and breaks encapsulation?

Comment: I don't know your exact use case. Circular references are not bad in general (js has no concept of "ownership", and they don't break encapsulation), but yes they are hard to update so you might want to avoid them if you can.

Comment: What do you mean JS has no concept of "ownership"?— just the way prototypal inheritance works I guess right? Also the use case is creating a game, which has Quests -> Tasks -> Activities -> NPCs (which can belong to Activities or Tasks). When the NPC does something, it needs to tell its parent.

Comment: I mean that JS as a language does not enforce "ownership" like some other languages do (mostly to manage memory allocation). Sure, you can organise your game state hierarchically if it makes sense for you.